# Script to set cell value from another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to call a value from another sheet(sheet3) within my spreadsheet and insert that value into the e.range.getRow(),13) (code provided below) on Sheet1. the value has specific spacing within the cell so I need it to call from the other sheet into this cell rather than just setting the value "location A" like it is now.

```html
else if(s.getName() == "Current Sales" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "Parts In Stock") {
 
    s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 13).setValue(s.getName()=="Validation Lists","A19");
    
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to access the other sheet.. what issue are you having? Review methods on the Apps Script documentation and reference (use the internet or the Script Editor help menu)

Comment: I updated the code above, sorry pasted code from another copy.

Answer (score 0):

```html
else if(s.getName() == "Current Sales" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "Parts In Stock") {
    var sheets = ss.getSheetByName("Validation Lists");
    var tema = sheets.getRange('a19').getValue();
    s.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 13).setValue(tema);
    
  }
```